# Apache2 doesn't properly redirect URLs with certain characters in them

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Given the following vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.subdomain.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web/

    <Directory /var/www/project/web/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(static)/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_project.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_project.log vhost_combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to redirect all requests **except** those starting with */static* (that's where the CSS, JS and images are) to a main controller, index.php, which will handle the routing to different modules.

It all works fine, until I try to access a link like this:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/view/10/Http%3A%2F%2Fnews.discovery.com%2Fspace%2Fnasa-installs-cosmic-ray-hunter
```

and Apache2 displays a **404** page, the request never makes it to the index.php file. Replacing all *%3A* and *%2F* in the link with something like a dash makes it work again.

Also tried to use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

but the same 404 happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual, in order to improve security, Apache will reject all URLs containing an encoded slash `%2F` with a 404.

In order to disable this behaviour, you need to set [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) to a value of `On` or `NoDecode`, preferably `NoDecode`.

This directive needs to be put either globally in the server config or in the virtual host definition and it will not work in *.htaccess*